# Python Scrapy can't extract text from class

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, css-selectors, scrapy

Please look this html code:

```
<header class="online">
                        <img src="http://static.flv.com/themes/h5/img/iconos/online.png"> <span>online</span> 
            <img src="http://static.flv.com/themes/h5/img/iconos/ojo16.png"> 428                        <p>xxfantasia</p>
</header>
```

I want to get the text inside (428, in this case). I used this:

```
        def parse(self, response):
            sel = Selector(response)
            cams = sel.css('header.online')
            for cam in cams:
                  print cam.css('text').extract()
```

I think i have used the correct css selector, but i got empty result.

Any help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

CSS selectors [don't normally have syntax to extract text content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

But Scrapy extends CSS selectors with the `::text` pseudo-element, so you want to use `cam.css('::text').extract()` that should give you the same thing as `cam.xpath('.//text()').extract()`

Note: Scrapy also adds the `::attr(attribute_name)` functional pseudo-element to extract attribute value (that's also not possible with standard CSS selectors)

Comment: With `cam.css('header.online::text').extract()` result like this:     

`[u' \n                ', u' 428                        ', u'\n        ']`  

How i can get only `[u'428']`?

Comment: You can use Python's `strip()` and `filter()` methods for example: `filter(bool, [e.strip() for e in cam.css('header.online::text').extract()])`